# How can I check auth user role in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have role column in users table, and I want to check the value like this in the blade file :

```
 @if ( {{Auth::user()->role }} == '1')
 // do something
 @endif
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: It's not a good practice to check roles inside blade but rather you should have different routes for each so it won't get messy as it the application gets bigger. Also try check the roles somewhere in `Middleware`

Comment: You posted too many questions and none accepted. This does not go well for your track record as a community member. You've been a member here long enough now and shouldn't use Stack as your free debugging/coding service.

Answer (score 6):

In blade files, you need to write plain PHP into the `@if` and others blade statements. So you would need to remove the `{{ }}`:

```
@if ( auth()->user()->role == 1)
 // do something
@endif
```

Comment: I got this;  errorErrorException in a3f1d34132d7ac5b21eb261386a3c286824a6b23.php line 54:
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\laravel5.2\users-project2\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php) (View: C:\laravel5.2\users-project2\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php)

Comment: Are you sure you have a user logged in?

Answer (score 1):

```
@if(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin')  == 'Admin')

// do something

@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can extend a blade.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#extending-blade

It's cool and convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of Laravel will work with like this. You don't need to use `{{}}` here.

```
 @if ( Auth::user()->role == 1)
 // do something
 @endif
```